# Convert a varchar(255) to a float in a stored procedure Round() function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, rounding

I have a stored procedure that needs to round a `varchar(255)` datatype. Upon trying to `round` this datatype, I got the error

> Error converting data type varchar to float

So I tried to convert the `varchar(255)` to a `float` in the `round` function. I have attached my Stored Procedure. There are 3 cases. the values in the [paramvalue] column can be '101.667483932', '27.63749569', etc... I need to round them to 1 decimal and then 2 decimals. Is this not the appropriate way to get round the [paramvalue] column?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ReportParameters]
        @StartTime datetime
        ,@EndTime datetime
        ,@UniqueID varchar(155)
AS
BEGIN

SELECT DISTINCT PA.[uniqueid]
      ,PA.[paramname]
      ,(SELECT PH.recipephase FROM BHPhase PH WHERE PH.uniqueid = PA.uniqueid AND PA.eventtime > PH.starttime AND PA.eventtime <= PH.endtime) AS Phase
      ,PA.[eu]
      ,CASE 
        WHEN PA.[eu] = 'pH' THEN ROUND (CONVERT(float, PA.[paramvalue]), 1)
        WHEN PA.[eu] = 'KG' THEN ROUND (CONVERT(float, PA.[paramvalue]), 1)
        WHEN PA.[eu] = 'mL/min' THEN ROUND (CONVERT(float, PA.[paramvalue]), 2)
        ELSE PA.paramvalue
       END
      ,PA.[paramtype]
      ,PA.[recipe]
      ,PA.[area]
      ,PA.[eventtime]
      ,PA.[userid]
FROM [BatchHistoryEx].[dbo].[BHParameter] PA
WHERE [eventtime] >= @StartTime AND [eventtime] <= @EndTime
AND PA.[paramtype] = 'Report'
AND PA.[uniqueid] = @UniqueID
ORDER BY [eventtime] ASC

End
```

Comment: if you use the correct datatype you'll never have this issue.

Comment: Why do you think you need to use `DISTINCT`? Is this just a standard practice of yours to add to every query? Given the predicate `PA.[uniqueid] = @UniqueID`, it appears that only one row should ever be selected (assuming the name of that column accurately reflects its usage).

Comment: And using 3-part names without a good reason is simply a problem that someone else will need to address at some point. If you need to refer to a database that is not the one in which your procedure exists, you should consider using synonyms or views. This will make your code more easily ported to a set of differently-named databases (because we often need to run multiple environments in the same instance).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TRY_CONVERT()`:

```
(CASE WHEN PA.[eu] = 'pH' THEN ROUND(TRY_CONVERT(float, PA.[paramvalue]), 1)
      WHEN PA.[eu] = 'KG' THEN ROUND(TRY_CONVERT(float, PA.[paramvalue]), 1)
      WHEN PA.[eu] = 'mL/min' THEN ROUND(TRY_CONVERT(float, PA.[paramvalue]), 2)
      ELSE PA.paramvalue
 END)
```